# How to build docker image inside docker container?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-in-docker

I am not sure I am doing it correct or not but I am trying to build a docker image inside docker container.

I think this can be achieve by using Docker-in-Docker but whenever I am trying to do that I am getting a following error while building an image:

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

**Here is my Dockerfile**

```
# FROM alpinelinux/docker-cli
FROM docker:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade

RUN apk add git

ENV REPOSITORY_URL=https://github.com/shahinadev/create-react-app.git
ENV PROJECT_NAME=create-react-app

RUN git clone ${REPOSITORY_URL} ${PROJECT_NAME}

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_NAME}

COPY Dockerfile Dockerfile

RUN docker build -t ${PROJECT_NAME} .
```

**Actual Result:**
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

**Expected Result:**
Image should build so that I can push it to the remote container registry

Comment: As no one has responded yet so i believe this is not possible but I found some open source projects like Kaniko which seems can solve my problem. But still I am trying to find out the solution to build an image inside container without any luck.